# Open most recent folder within sub folder and open workbook based on name

Tags: excel, vba, directory

As the title suggests, my objective is to open the most recently modified folder. Within this folder, I wish to open each sub folder and open each file with "summary" in it, then close. This is what i have so far:

```
Option Explicit
Function GetLastFolder(Path As String)
    Dim FSO, FS, F, DtLast As Date, Result As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FS = FSO.GetFolder(Path).SubFolders
    For Each F In FS
        If F.DateLastModified > DtLast Then
             DtLast = F.DateLastModified
             Result = F.Name
        End If
    Next
    GetLastFolder = Result
End Function

Sub OpenFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Folder As String

GetLastFolder ("H:\myFile\")

Dim numberOfFolders As Long

numberOfFolders = GetLastFolder.Files.Count

mylist = Array("File1", "File2", "File3")

For i = 0 To numberOfFolders
If Folder.Exists(mylist(i)) Then

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

My function locates the most recent folder and the sub procedure is supposed to do the rest. I'm hoping that my loop will enter each sub folder `numberOfFolder` amount of times which is called the name of the array before opening the file. My attempt is weak, especially when I arrive at the loop. I'm not sure how to reference folders and files which are not pre-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your GetLastFolder seems fine.

Try this OpenFolder to get you going:

```
Sub OpenFolder()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Folder As String, sPath As String
    Dim numberOfFolders As Long
    Dim oFolder As Object, oSubFolder As Object, oFSO As Object

    sPath = "C:\Program Files\"
    numberOfFolders = 0
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Folder = GetLastFolder("C:\Program Files\")

    Set oFolder = oFSO.getfolder(sPath + Folder)

    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.subfolders
        numberOfFolders = numberOfFolders + 1
    Next

    MsgBox numberOfFolders

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked a treat!